# button over webview not working

Tags: android, webview, android-framelayout

my xml file:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/groupon_web">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Groupon_webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/not_favorite"
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

But navigation button in toolbar works pretty well. I don't know why the button above webview doesn't work at all. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Put your webview , toolbar and button inside relative layout. Inside your frame layout. Use the same hierarchy.